# Как проскалировать изображение на камере по осям в Unity3D 5

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Мне нужно сузить изображение на экране в `Unity3D 5` в `a` раз по оси `X` и в `b` раз по оси `Y`. Пробовал изменять на камере значения `scale` по осям, но ничего не менялось

Comment: постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вроде дополнил, просто не знаю как еще более подробно написать

Comment: Попробуйте рендерить на текстуру, и потом уже ее выводить со скейлом.

Comment: @trollingchar Да спасибо, я сделал средерил на текстуру а потом закинул ее на канвас